# Incorrect Content-Type Received in Response Headers When Using Spring Boot RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

In the provided code snippet, I'm making an HTTP GET request using Spring Boot's RestTemplate. The intention is to execute specific business logic based on the Content-Type of the response received from the URL. However, for the URL https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London, I've encountered a disparity in the Content-Type value retrieved from the response compared to what's observed when the same request is performed using tools like Postman or curl.

Here's the code I'm using to make the request:

```
String url = "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

if (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8.equals(response.getHeaders().getContentType())
        || MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.equals(response.getHeaders().getContentType())) {
    // Execute logic for JSON response
} else {
    // Execute logic for other response types
}
```

My query pertains to resolving this discrepancy and ensuring that the Content-Type header received through RestTemplate is consistent with the headers obtained through tools like Postman or curl. It's noteworthy that the URL provided for the request is subject to dynamic input from end-users, thereby indicating that the response body and Content-Type could vary.

I'm keen on understanding how I can rectify this situation and consistently obtain the correct Content-Type through RestTemplate. The solution I'm seeking should accommodate the dynamic nature of the URL and adapt to potential changes in response content and Content-Type.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate which content type you want to process by adding an `Accept` header:

```
headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
```

PS: When executing the request I noticed that the request isn't always successful, so you will need to handle that.